# Converting only a individual single letter from lowercase to uppercase in python csv reader

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, csv, replace

I want to convert all the `i` (in lower case) to its upper case, i.e. (`I`). I am merging 2 rows of a csv file and printing it. I want to replace all the individual characters (`i`) to their uppercase form (`I`). This should not be applied to other strings in the text file, like `is`, `itself`, `it`, `in` etc. I have tried, but not getting the desired output. Any help is deeply appreciated.

```
import csv, string, re, nltk
def process_reqs():
    with open('res.csv') as f:
       reader = csv.reader(f)
       next(reader, None)
       global raw_text
       with open('raw_res.txt', 'w', encoding = 'utf-8') as f1:
          rows = ('"{}."'.format(' '.join(row)) for row in reader)
          raw_text = ', '.join(rows)
          for word in raw_text.split():
              if word == 'i':
                 raw_text = raw_text.replace(word, "I")
          f1.write(raw_text)
          print(raw_text)
process_reqs()
```

Comment: this code is doing much more than the question, i.e. throwing away the first/header row, updating to apparently unrelated global variables (`raw_text`), are these actually relevant?  see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I'd suggest editing your question to give an example of some input and the expected output, what you're doing at the moment looks very weird

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a simple string replacement. Just don't forget the spaces, i.e replace (" i ") by (" I ").